# Harry Potter Fanfiction-Title The Sir and Ma'am Chronicles

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

I am looking for a fanfiction. The title is The Sir and Ma'am Chronicles. The story was posted on fanfiction.net. It is about an abused Harry and Hermione who are adopted by the Weasleys.

Comment: Can you remember anything about this that you could [edit] in? What happens in it? When did you read it? Etc.

Comment: I'm assuming that you've tried searching for that title on FanFiction.net? If it's no longer there, it may have been removed, in which case the best place to look for it would be the [Wayback Machine](https://archive.org/web/web.php).

Comment: It would appear that that author has deleted their account on FF and requested that their writings be removed. I can't see anywhere else online that they post. I've found a few snippets of the work and googled them, but the archived stories have been deleted from google also, presumably by request.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this story has been *intentionally removed* by the author from FanFiction.net.

Comment: @Valorum to be honest that seems like it could be the answer rather than a reason to close it. Just unfortunate that it’s been removed.